# Szimek Signature_Pad - Sending signed image with PHP Mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am searching for a way to integrate [szimek/signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) with PHP mail.

Signature_Pad includes a way to display a captured signed image as **data:image/png;base64** and I've found a way to store this information in a directory on the server by using a hidden field on the form submit page (index.php) and by editing app.js with the following code:

index.php

```
<form id="sigform" action="myscript.php" method="post">
    <input id="siginput" type="hidden" name="sig" value="" />
</form>
```

app.js

```
var form = document.getElementById("sigform"),
    input = document.getElementById("siginput")

savePNGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
           alert("Please provide signature first.");
       } else {
           input.value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
           form.submit();
       }
});
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'captured/');
    $sig = $_POST['sig'];
    $sig = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $sig);
    $sig = str_replace(' ', '+', $sig);
    $data = base64_decode($sig);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . "Signature" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s-").time(). ".png";
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

How would I go about retrieving the specific signed signature image from a folder on the server then send it through php mail?

Another resource that accomplishes a similar task is [zetakey/signsend](https://github.com/zetakey/signsend) however I would prefer to use szimek/signature_pad due to it's styling and resizability.

I've searched several articles online and have not yet been able to find a straight forward way to accomplish this using php mail.

Please let me know if you need any additional information and thanks in advance for any possible assistance that you may be able to provide.

Comment: You probably need a `Data Structure` like a database or something like that to store the record info + the file name in it in order to be able to retrieve it later...

Comment: Hi EhsanT, thank you for the reply. I'm not sure if that is the case as the example zetakey/signsend does not use a database. In both examples zetakey/signsend and szimek/signature_pad are both capable of saving the signed image to a folder directory on the server using PHP. I'm just not sure how to get a specific signed image from the folder and send it through php mail, etc with szimek/signature_pad.

Comment: I really still do not know your issue. If you want to send the email right after storing the image, you can store the image name and path in a variable and then use same variable in your email. But if you want to use it in future, then you need to store it in some data structure and retrieve it later. So your code is ready for the first case, you can use `$file` to send it's link in your email or even attach the file to your email. But if your question is something else, please elaborate more in the origin of your question

Comment: Hi EhsanT, "I am searching for a way to integrate szimek/signature_pad with PHP mail." I would like to attach a captured signed image using szimek/signature_pad then upon form submit send that specific image using php mail. I will further test your suggestion of  using $file to send it's link in the email or even attach the file to your email and follow up with the results and complete code. Thanks!

Comment: Great, unfortunately I'm not familiar with _szimek/signature_pad_ so my suggestion is based on your php code and your need of attaching a image stored on the server in your email. For attaching the image to the email, you need a base64 encoded string and you have `$sig`. You can use it, but for sending the link of the image, you can use `$file`. Hope I could help you :)